# Efficient (& perhaps shortest) way of getting a list of column names that satisfies a condition, for each row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have a dataframe with 5 columns (first column is ID and 4 are country names)

I want a list of country names for each row, that satisfies a particular condition on that respective country column.

[image]

```
df = {'id':['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5'], 'c1':[3,2,4,1,4], 'c2':[4,2,5,5,5], 'c3':[4,5,3,3,3], 'c4':[5,1,2,2,2]}
```

In the above case I need a IDs for which rating is 4 and above.

I'm expecting the output to be list of companies for where rating was 4 and above for each ID. Can be a dataframe or a dict.

```
highest_rated_companies = { 'i1': ['c2', 'c3', 'c4'], 'i2': ['c3'], 'i3': ['c1', 'c2'], 'i4': ['c2'], 'i5': ['c1', 'c2'] }
```

Comment: kindly share data not pics, in this case your input dataframe

Comment: What have you tried? Where did it go wrong? Is the output to be understood as a dictionary as you wrote it or implicitly as a data frame again?

Comment: @ Sorry, I have shared the data

Comment: @DavidWierichs The output can be a dictionary or a dataframe. I'm looking for a short code. I got it done using 2 'for loops', but that's not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this, with a `to_records`, that seems to be the fastest as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45695288/13676202):

**First Option**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'id':['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5'], 'c1':[3,2,4,1,4], 'c2':[4,2,5,5,5], 'c3':[4,5,3,3,3], 'c4':[5,1,2,2,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
highest_rated_companies={row[1]:[df.columns[idx] for idx,val in enumerate(list(row)[2:],1) if val>=4] for row in df.to_records()}
```

**Second Option**

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id':['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5'], 'c1':[3,2,4,1,4], 'c2':[4,2,5,5,5], 'c3':[4,5,3,3,3], 'c4':[5,1,2,2,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
highest_rated_companies={row[0]:[df.columns[idx] for idx,val in enumerate(row[1:],1) if val>=4] for i, row in df.iterrows()}
print(highest_rated_companies)
```

Both outputs:

```
df:

   id  c1  c2  c3  c4
0  i1   3   4   4   5
1  i2   2   2   5   1
2  i3   4   5   3   2
3  i4   1   5   3   2
4  i5   4   5   3   2


highest_rated_companies:

{'i1': ['c2', 'c3', 'c4'], 'i2': ['c3'], 'i3': ['c1', 'c2'], 'i4': ['c2'], 'i5': ['c1', 'c2']}
```

Timestamps:

**First Option:**

- `0.0113047` seconds best case, when executed `100` times the script
- `1.2424291999999468` seconds best case, when executed `10000` times the script

**Second Option**

- `0.07292359999996734` seconds best case, when executed `100` times the script
- `7.821904700000005` seconds best case, when executed `10000` times the script

**Edit:**

Using `dt.to_records()`, seem to be the fastest way, since I tested Ehsan's answer and I got when executed `10000` times the script, a timestamp of `50.64001639999992` seconds, and  when executed `100` times the script, a timestamp of `0.5399872999998934` seconds. Even it's faster than the **Second Option**, the **First Option** keep being the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
keys, values = np.where(df[['c1','c2','c3','c4']].ge(4))
highest_rated_companies = pd.DataFrame({'id':df.iloc[keys].id,'c':df.columns[values+1]})
```

output:

```
   id   c
0  i1  c2
0  i1  c3
0  i1  c4
1  i2  c3
2  i3  c1
2  i3  c2
3  i4  c2
4  i5  c1
4  i5  c2
```

You can easily convert it to a dictionary if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `to_dict` method.  If you set your `id` column as the index, you can do:

```
df = df[df>=4]
d = df.to_dict('index')
output = {ID: [name for name,val in row.items() if not pd.isnull(val)] for ID, row in d.items()}
```

The last line is to convert the dictionary into the desired format.  Time test:

```
In[0]:
import pandas as pd

df = {'id':['i1','i2','i3','i4','i5'], 'c1':[3,2,4,1,4], 'c2':[4,2,5,5,5], 'c3':[4,5,3,3,3], 'c4':[5,1,2,2,2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df.set_index('id',drop=True)
df = df[df>=4]

%%timeit -n 1000
d = df.to_dict('index')
output = {ID: [name for name,val in row.items() if not pd.isnull(val)] for ID, row in d.items()}

Out[0]
243 µs ± 23.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**This isn't as fast as what @MrNobody33 answered, though**:
`135 µs ± 4.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`